# В разных версиях Matlab функция atan возвращaeт разный результат

Tags: matlab

Почему в

MATLAB Version: 8.1.0.604 (R2013a)

```
>> sin(2+3i)*atan(4i)/(1-6i)

ans =

-1.8009 - 1.9190i

>> sin(2+3i)*atan((4i))/(1-6i)

ans =

  -1.8009 - 1.9190i

>> atan(4i)

ans =

  -1.5708 + 0.2554i
```

MATLAB Version 6.5.0.180913a (R13)

```
>> sin(2+3i)*atan(4i)/(1-6i)

ans =

1.1002 + 2.3907i

>> sin(2+3i)*atan((4i))/(1-6i)

ans =

   1.1002 + 2.3907i

>> atan(4i)

ans =

   1.5708 + 0.2554i
```

Объясните пожалуйста, почему так?
И чему же все-таки равен atan(4i)?

Comment: а нигде нет переопределения sin или atan? Помню, в институте у одного препода была такая проблема - он дома на 6.1 все подготовил, но в инсте стоял 7.0, у них разный порядок загрузки функций и его функция inf в 6.1 превратилась просто в бесконечность в 7.0 и не выполнялась.

Comment: Переопределения нет, использовал clear

Comment: clear может и не помочь если где-то в области видимости валяется другая функция с таким же именем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Провёл небольшое исследование и выяснил следующее. Если скормить WolframAlpha вот эти уравнения (если не заметили, то я в левой части `i` заменил на `x`):

[`sin(2+3x)*atan(4x)/(1-6x) = 1.1002 + 2.3907i`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%282%2B3x%29*atan%284x%29%2F%281-6x%29+%3D+1.1002+%2B+2.3907i)

и

[`sin(2+3x)*atan(4x)/(1-6x) = -1.8009 - 1.9190i`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%282%2B3x%29*atan%284x%29%2F%281-6x%29+%3D+-1.8009+-+1.9190i),

то среди их корней будет и `x = i` (с некоторой погрешностью). Это наводит на мысль, что оба результата верны. Однако по тем или иным причинам Matlab в разных версиях отдаёт предпочтение разным вариантам. Возможно, в какой-то версии между 6.5.0.180913a и 8.1.0.604 был переработан алгоритм работы тригонометрических функций или функций, работающих с комплексныыми числами. Возможно, вам стоит обратиться на форум [Математика](http://math.hashcode.ru/), есть шанс, что там сидят люди, знакомые с такой ситуацией.

P. S. [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%282%2B3i%29*atan%284i%29%2F%281-6i%29) считает, что правильный ответ 1.1002 + 2.3907i

Comment: Оба ответа верны быть не могут, но вы правы
в новой и старой версии matlab atan(4i) дает разные результаты

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего причина в порядке выполнения математических операций! Для  точности сравнения внесите аргумент арктангенса в скобки! Видимо приоритет гость у версий разная! Будет интересно увидеть результат!

Comment: Внес аргумент арктангенса в скобки - ничего не изменилось, что и следовало ожидать.